# Terminology for pairs of words with the same meaning, similar or same pronunciation but different spelling

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography, terminology

Is there a term describe word pairs like *colour/color* that have the same meaning, similar or same pronunciation but a different spelling?

The most common examples I can think of are English/American spelling variants, though there are alternative transliterations of foreign words would fit the bill too (e.g., *Ziggurat/Ziqqurat*).

I was wondering if there is a recognised word for describing these word pairings as we have terminology like "homonym", "heteronym" etc. for words with different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you could be looking for is [variant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variant)

Definition:

> 1 obsolete : variable
>
> 2 : manifesting variety, deviation, or disagreement
>
> 3 : varying usually slightly from the standard form
>
> *(examples) variant readings;
> variant spellings*

Also, from google search:
[image]

Comment: He already mentioned *variant* — and *alternative* — in his original posting.

Comment: @tchrist Hence the *could be*. You've never used a word and then later realized it was the word you were looking for to begin with? I was throwing that suggestion out there because it has been used in the way his question is asking.

Comment: @tchrist And variant may be the best descriptor.

Comment: Souta that's exactly what happened in this case. I used the word 'variant' thought there must be a better word, but I'm now persuaded that it's probably the best word in the situation.

Answer (score 2):

This diagram on Wikipedia suggests that there is no such word:

[image]

Comment: The lack of inclusion in a diagram proves that something doesn't exist?

Comment: neat diagram though :)  Looks like a transit map

Comment: @bib Pitarou never said that it didn't exist, just said that *Wikipedia **suggests** that there is no such word* (in Pitarou's defense)

Comment: @bib No, it doesn't.  The kind of proof you seem to be asking for is all but impossible.  But, to reiterate, I think this diagram **is** suggestive.

Comment: I came across that diagram when I was 'researching' (or dare I say Googling) this issue. I had actually thought of posting it in my initial question. But thanks for posting it, I think it illuminates an opportunity for creative lexicologists.