# The same pronunciation but spelled differently

Tags: synonyms, terminology, orthography

What do we call words that sound (pronunciation) similar but have different spellings?

Just for example :

> come - *kom*
>   you  - *u*

I've already seen this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83936/terminology-for-pairs-of-words-with-the-same-meaning-similar-or-same-pronunciat) but that does not comply with the examples I have shown.

Are there any words like that?

Comment: The answer you accepted is [one of the answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/83937/44619) given in the same post which you linked. I propose that your question is really a duplicate of the question whose link I have posted

Comment: _Kom_ and _u_ are not words at all. Your examples thus do not fit the question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone):

"A **homophone** is a word that is pronounced the same as another word but differs in meaning, and may differ in spelling. The words may be spelled the same, such as rose (flower) and rose (past tense of "rise"), or differently, such as carat, caret, and carrot, or to, two, and too."