# What is a short term for words that have more than one spelling?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, adjectives

Is there a word or short term for words that have multiple valid spellings that don't correspond to any differences in meaning or pronunciation? The different spellings can be described as "spelling variants", but I'm looking for a word to describe the words themselves. I don't consider the term "homophones" (or the more specific "heterographic homophones") to be applicable because I understand it to refer to words that have different meanings.

A noun would be ideal ("*Ax(e)* is a(n) __") but an adjective that can modify a noun like *word* would be OK too ("*Ax(e)* is a(n) __ word"). To be clear, in this sentence I am using *ax(e)* to refer to the word itself, not to either of its two spelling variants. The word *ax(e)* is not a "variant" (n.): it comprises the two variant spellings <ax> and <axe>. I guess *ax(e)* could be described as a "variant word", using the adjective definition of *variant* that means something like "exhibiting variation", but I don't like this very much because it seems too ambiguous or unclear to me. However, if somebody can post an answer showing that "variant word" is some kind of established term for words like *ax(e)*, I would be grateful for that information.

#### I'm not looking for the word *variant*

The questions *[Terminology for pairs of words with the same meaning, similar or same pronunciation but different spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83936/terminology-for-pairs-of-words-with-the-same-meaning-similar-or-same-pronunciat?rq=1)* and *[Is there a word to describe words that can be spelled different ways?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412983/is-there-a-word-to-describe-words-that-can-be-spelled-different-ways)* both look similar to mine, but neither has any answers that fit my sentence. I want to emphasize again that *variant* doesn't work for my purposes because I'm not looking for a word to describe the pair of spelling variants; I want a word to describe the single word corresponding to the multiple spelling variants.

#### If no such word exists, what is a good phrase for this?

I realize that such a word might not exist (as Pitarou's answer to the first linked question suggests); in that case, I'd be interested in hearing suggestions for a good multi-word term. The best I was able to come up with was "words with spelling variants not associated with different meanings or different pronunciations", which is pretty long.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one such spelling. I guess, I have an answer!

Comment: @ubihatt: I used the example *ax/axe* in the sentence at the end. Other examples are *gray/grey, judgment/judgement, cipher/cypher.*

Comment: does this include color/colour?

Comment: @ubihatt: Sure, I don't mind if someone suggests a term that includes words like *color/colour.* I just didn't include them in my list because I thought that some people might think of "colour" as a "wrong" spelling in American English, and vice versa for "color" in British English, so it doesn't seem like a prototypical example of a word with multiple valid spelling variants

Comment: Some spellings have different orthography. This [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83936/terminology-for-pairs-of-words-with-the-same-meaning-similar-or-same-pronunciat?rq=1)  and this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437252/word-for-nouns-with-multiple-plural-forms/459121#459121) may throw some light.

Comment: I think you definitely need to distinguish between words that are different in AE and BE (such as gray vs grey) and words that can be spelled differently within one language.

Comment: @MrLister: Neither *gray* nor *grey* is completely restricted to one side of the Atlantic. The relative frequencies are switched, but most dictionaries and usage guides don't say that it's incorrect to use *grey* in the US or *gray* in the UK (at most, they might say that one or the other is "preferred" in a certain region).

Comment: @sumelic [Some](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gray) [dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gray) say "US spelling of grey" for "gray".

Comment: @ubihatt: Thanks for the links! That first question does seem almost the same as mine, although unfortunately I don't find the accepted answer at all satisfactory. (As I said in my post, "variant" doesn't describe the words, but rather their spellings, which isn't what I want.) Also, I only want a word that describes spelling variants that have the exact same pronunciation, not ones that have "similar" pronunciations.

Comment: You're looking at this synchronically, which doesn't much work. Diachronically, all words have had multiple spellings. Far more still do than most people realize because of our consensually constructed concord. Per Mark Twain: “I never had any large respect for good spelling. That is my feeling yet. Before the spelling-book came with its arbitrary forms, men unconsciously revealed shades of their characters and also added enlightening shades of expression to what they wrote by their spelling, and so it is possible that the spelling-book has been a doubtful benevolence to us.” :)

Comment: @sumelic - I’ve nothing against SWR, but why in  must it be a single word in this case?

Comment: @user070221: As I said in the first sentence, either a word or a short term is fine. (I have also used the tag "phrase-requests" as well as SWR.)

Comment: Ooh, magic powers. I keep forgetting that I can change the course of history with my dupehammer....

Answer (score 2):

There is no word for this. You could coin "synograph" and see if it takes off, but there isn't a single word for it.

"Words with more than one spelling" or "words with variant spellings" (or "spelling variants") would be the clearest.

*Colour* and *color* are an example of regional variation.